# vaadin7: com.vaadin.ui.UI class isn't visible

Tags: java, user-interface, maven-2, vaadin7

I have a vaadin6 application that I have to upgrade to vaadin7.

I used this document to understand vaadin6 to vaadin7 migrating:

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Migrating+from+Vaadin+6+to+Vaadin+7

Then I tried to build the application (with maven2) with vaadin7.0.0.alpha3 repository.
Obviously many errors appears because of the differences between vaadin6 API and vaadin7 API.
One of those errors that I have to correct is:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getMainWindow()
location: class com.vaadin.Application
```

What I understood is that I have to use com.vaadin.ui.UI instead of com.vaadin.Application.
But the problem is that when I add

```
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
```

Then I tried to build again this error appears:

```
[ERROR] D:\aperte-workflow\core\gui-commons\src\main\java\org\aperteworkflo\util\vaadin\VaadinUtility.java:[53,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class UI
location: package com.vaadin.ui
```

I'm sure that I'm using vaadin7.0.0 repository. I checked also that com.vaadin.ui.UI class exists in the repository that I'm using:

https://vaadin.com/api/7.0.0/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html

So what's the problem?

Comment: I think VaadinUtility is still using Vaadin 6 classes.

Comment: I would also suggest using the newest 7.3.0 repository. There have been lots of changes between 7.0 and 7.3, so better start using the latest stuff right away: https://vaadin.com/api/7.3.0/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html

But can't really say why the UI class is not found from the classpath.

Comment: Hi Omar, have you found any solution? I am facing the same issue when i try to ant clean deploy my vaadin portlet.